# How do I extract a field from a dataset .txt file and save it in a new file using terminal on a Mac?

Tags: mac, terminal, extract

I want to extract the 9th field from the data set and save it in a new file using terminal.

This is what I have:

```
cut -f 9 file.txt > newFile.txt
```

When I run this command, it extracts the whole file and creates a new file with all of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use a delimiter. For example, in this file I hace a space of separator between characters:

$ cat a.txt

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
a b c d e f g h i
```

$ cut -d" " -f9 a.txt

```
9
i
```

If your file the characters are separed by a '-' for example, change the -d parameter:

$ cut -d" " -f9 b.txt

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9
a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i
```

$ cut -d"-" -f9 b.txt

```
9
1
```

This is an extract of the manual:

```
-d, --delimiter=DELIM
              use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
```

You can also try with another commands like awk:

$ awk '{print $9}' a.txt

```
9
1
```